# Icefaces set focus not working

Tags: jsf, icefaces, jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I am trying to set focus to a component in Icefaces 1.8.2, but it doesn't work probably because of the component not being rendered at the time of the method call.
Any ideas?

```
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(getContext(),
                "document.getElementById('"+ getClientId(component) + "').focus();");
```

Comment: Provide more detail please, when do you want to add focus? After what? Show us more code.

Comment: Obviously after all the rendering has finished. I placed this line after the end of all server calls, but no idea when Icefaces executes this call

Comment: Could you try to call this via javascript function from `oncomplete` of your action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, I messed it up somewhere previously..

```
JavascriptContext.applicationFocus(getContext(), getClientId(component));


public static String getClientId(UIComponent component) {
    return component.getClientId(getContext());
}

public static FacesContext getContext() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
}
```